# ASP button not posting back after exporting a pdf from ashx using response.write

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I am exporting a pdf from a json string from database. *My export buttons are in a gridview control -  Image buttons*. I am using a Handler (ashx) file for exporting.

The problem is, after exporting the buttons on the page (one button and one command field) are not posting back. My handler code and aspx code are below

Handler

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.html;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Data;
using GE.MSA.DataQuality.DataAccess;
using GE.MSA.DataQuality.DataAccess.Authentication;
using GE.MSA.DataQuality.DataAccess.EntityModel;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace GE.MSA.DataQuality.Web
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for CreatePDF
    /// </summary>
    public class CreatePDF : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            //context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            //context.Response.Write("Hello World");

            int _id = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["Id"]);
            string _report = context.Request.QueryString["Report"];
            string _lockedfrom = context.Request.QueryString["LockedFrom"];
            string _lockedto = context.Request.QueryString["LockedTo"];
            string _docheader = (_report == "CostServiceReport" ? "Cost & Service Report - " : "Service Report - ") + "Locked from : " + _lockedfrom + " to " + _lockedto;
            string _doctitle = _report + "-" + _lockedfrom + "-" + _lockedto + ".pdf";

            DataTable _PDFReport = new DataTable();

            if (_report == "CostServiceReport")
            {
                using (var db = new dbReferenceTablesEntities())
                {
                    string csr = (from i in db.CS_Billing_LockPeriod
                                  where i.ID == _id
                                  select i.CostServiceReport).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
                    _PDFReport = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(csr, _PDFReport.GetType());
                }
            }

            else
            {
                if (_report == "ServiceReport")
                {
                    using (var db = new dbReferenceTablesEntities())
                    {
                        string sr = (from i in db.CS_Billing_LockPeriod
                                     where i.ID == _id
                                     select i.ServiceReport).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
                        _PDFReport = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sr, _PDFReport.GetType());
                    }
                }
            }

            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A3, 20, 20, 20, 20);
            pdfDoc.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A3.Rotate());
            try
            {
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
                pdfDoc.Open();
                Chunk c = new Chunk("" + _docheader + "", FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 15));
                Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
                p.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                p.Add(c);
                pdfDoc.Add(p);
                string clientLogo = context.Server.MapPath(".") + "/images/abc.png";
                string imageFilePath = context.Server.MapPath(".") + "/images/abc.png";
                iTextSharp.text.Image jpg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageFilePath);

                //Resize image depend upon your need   
                jpg.ScaleToFit(60f, 40f);

                //Give space before image   
                jpg.SpacingBefore = 0f;

                //Give some space after the image   
                jpg.SpacingAfter = 1f;
                jpg.Alignment = Element.HEADER;
                pdfDoc.Add(jpg);
                Font font8 = FontFactory.GetFont("ARIAL", 7);
                DataTable dt = _PDFReport;
                if (dt != null & dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    //Craete instance of the pdf table and set the number of column in that table  
                    PdfPTable PdfTable = new PdfPTable(dt.Columns.Count);
                    PdfTable.HeaderRows = 1;
                    PdfPCell PdfPCell = null;

                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        PdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk(dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString(), FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 12))));
                        PdfPCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                        PdfPCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
                        PdfPCell.BackgroundColor = new Color(109, 159, 213);
                        PdfTable.AddCell(PdfPCell);
                    }

                    for (int rows = 0; rows < dt.Rows.Count; rows++)
                    {
                        for (int column = 0; column < dt.Columns.Count; column++)
                        {
                            PdfPCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk(dt.Rows[rows][column].ToString(), font8)));
                            PdfTable.AddCell(PdfPCell);
                        }
                    }
                    //PdfTable.SpacingBefore = 15f; // Give some space after the text or it may overlap the table            
                    pdfDoc.Add(PdfTable); // add pdf table to the document   
                }
                pdfDoc.Close();
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename= " + _doctitle);
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(pdfDoc);
                context.Response.Flush();
                HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
            }
            catch (DocumentException de)
            {
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(de.Message);
            }
            catch (IOException ioEx)
            {
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(ioEx.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ASPX Page

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="LockForcing.aspx.cs" Inherits="GE.MSA.DataQuality.Web.LockForcing" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <h2>Lock Force Calculation</h2>
            <div>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Set Lock Period</legend>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label>Start Month</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStartMonth" runat="server" Width="100%">
                                    <asp:ListItem>01</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>02</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>03</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>04</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>05</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>06</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>07</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>08</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>09</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>11</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>12</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList></li></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>
                                <label>Start Year</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStartYear" runat="server" Width="100%">
                                </asp:DropDownList></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label>End Month</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEndMonth" runat="server" Width="100%">
                                    <asp:ListItem>01</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>02</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>03</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>04</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>05</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>06</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>07</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>08</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>09</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>11</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>12</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>
                                <label>End Year</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEndYear" runat="server" Width="100%">
                                </asp:DropDownList></td>

                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnLock" runat="server" Width="120px" Text="Lock" CssClass="submitButton"
                                    BorderStyle="None" OnClick="btnLock_Click" />
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblLockMessage"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="5000" Enabled="false" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div>
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Lock Period Details</label>
                        </td>
                        <td align="right">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblmsg"></asp:Label>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <asp:GridView ID="gvLockPeriod" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="mGrid" OnRowDeleting="gvLockPeriod_RowDeleting"
                                DataKeyNames="Id">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" ControlStyle-ForeColor="darkcyan" DeleteText="Unlock"></asp:CommandField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="FromDate" HeaderText="FromDate" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ToDate" HeaderText="ToDate" />
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cost&ServiceReport">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/images/Pdf-16.png" runat="server" ToolTip="Download Cost & Service Report"
                                                Visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("CostServiceReport")) %>'
                                                PostBackUrl='<%#"CreatePDF.ashx?id="+Eval("Id")+"&Report=CostServiceReport"+"&LockedFrom="+Eval("fromdate")+"&LockedTo="+Eval("todate")+""%>' />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ServiceReport">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/images/Pdf-16.png" runat="server" ToolTip="Download Service Report"
                                                Visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("ServiceReport")) %>'
                                                PostBackUrl='<%#"CreatePDF.ashx?id="+Eval("Id")+"&Report=ServiceReport"+"&LockedFrom="+Eval("fromdate")+"&LockedTo="+Eval("todate")+""%>' />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ModifiedBy" HeaderText="CreatedUser" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ModifiedDate" HeaderText="CreatedDate" />
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
     <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <div class="overlays" />
            <div style="font-weight: bold; align-content: center" class="overlayContents">
                <asp:Image ID="aspImg1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/ajax-loader.GIF" />
            </div>
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

After flushing the response call the response end method.

```
context.Response.Flush();
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```